# How to represent SIP-adress in OpenID Connect

Tags: sip, openid-connect

In the [standard claims](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#StandardClaims), it says that for `phone_number`, E.164 is recommended, but if it is `verified` it is required.  I want to let the user give a SIP-address as phone-number, and let the system mark it as verified when that's the case.

I can see a few options, all suboptimal:

1. Hold the SIP-adress as a separate claim, e.g. `sip_address` and `sip_address_verified`.
2. Break the **MUST** and give a sip-address in `phone_number`.
3. Skip usage of `phone_number_verified` or just have an alternative field for only the `verified` component.

Answer (score 1):

2. makes your system violate the spec, that leaves 1. and 3.